# How did Vastra and Jenny meet?

Tags: doctor-who

As a huge fan of [Shoujo Ai/Yuri](http://vndb.org/g97), Vastra's and Jenny's relationship intrigues me greatly.

The first time I remember seeing Vastra and Jenny was in the episode *A Good Man Goes to War* when The 11th Doctor (Matt Smith) gathers allies and storms Demon's Run to rescue Amy and

> her baby Melody.

As the series progressed it's revealed that Vastra and Jenny are practically lovers so ideally I would have loved to know how all of that started (sure, Vastra's "a lizard" but love knows no barriers).

From what I understand, Vastra met the Doctor some time where Vastra was murdering innocents in revenge of her slain sister before the Doctor stopped her, saving her and incurring a debt to him.

At first I thought her to be Restac and her sister being Alaya, both from the episodes *The Hungry Earth* and *Cold Blood* but then I remembered that those episodes weren't set before Victoria London, so unless Restac time traveled (via the cracks in reality?) she couldn't be Vastra under a different name

Now I was pretty sure I saw every episode involving Matt Smith's Doctor and I can't get any publications easily so I am wondering, how/when did Vastra and Jenny meet/fall in love?

Comment: “practically lovers” — I believe [they’re married](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jenny_Flint#Defeating_the_Great_Intelligence).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite however Vastra says in *Deep Breath* that for appearance Jenny is her maid, so while they say they are married i can't in good conscience call it marriage if they can display it out in public

Comment: that’s easy for you to say! Do you know the kind of prejudice that same-sex-different-species relationships faced in Victorian London?!?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well it's just my view on marriage since one's marriage shouldn't be hidden away from the world, regardless of the gender or species (Silurians, Yukos, Gira) of the couple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Vastra,_Jenny_Flint,_and_Strax

> Vastra is a female Silurian warrior from prehistoric Earth who was
>   awakened from hibernation in the 19th century when her lair was
>   disturbed during the construction of the London Underground.
>   Initially enraged, and after slaughtering five commuters, she was
>   pacified by the Doctor and eventually overcame her race's hatred of
>   humans to become a part of London society and a consulting detective
>   to Scotland Yard and a possible inspiration for the Sherlock Holmes
>   stories.
>
> Jenny's backstory shows she was turned away from her family because of
>   her "preferences in companionship", and saved from attackers by
>   Vastra, who took her on as an employee. The Doctor was present at
>   their initial meeting, during which he saved Jenny's life. She shows
>   herself to have acquired extremely formidable skills as a hand-to-hand
>   combatant and a swordswoman. She has also become familiarized with
>   future concepts involving technology.

There are no sources for this, but I'm assuming this is pieced together from exposition provided in the episodes. http://tardis.wikia.com/ contains similar entries.

Comment: No, none of that is from the TV show.

Answer (score 6):

1. Vastra and Jenny are not *"practically lovers"*, they are **married.**
2. Their meeting was not shown on screen. I am not sure if it has been in book form, or if it will.

Comment: I still hope they create a new spin-off around their stories, especially due to Strax as well. As far that's been the initial idea for/after their introduction, but they didn't pull it off so far. :)

Comment: @Mario that's something fans have been asking for basically since the characters were introduced. Moffat was actually considering it at one point, but had to drop the idea because he was too busy running both Doctor Who and Sherlock. So don't expect it any time soon

Comment: @Jason I wish he'd just let someone else do it. Not going to happen though, because Moffat is Moffat's biggest fan.

Comment: @Adeptus in fairness to Moffat, they are his characters. I'm not sure how the BBC handles creative control of the characters its writers create (I know back in the 60s the Daleks were owned by Terry Nation, which occasionally caused problems), so that may be a factor. But even if he passed the bulk of the duties to someone else, any kind of creative involvement would be too much, especially when he can barely put out a full season of his other shows in a single year

Comment: @Jason Yeah, OK. So, he needs to pass on the other shows...

Answer (score 1):

The story of Madame Vastra's first meeting with Jenny is told in the short story "*Madame Vastra*" found in [The Brilliant Book 2012](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Brilliant_Book_2012) (available to read online [here](https://archive.org/details/brilliantbook2010000unse)).

In brief, Jenny was being assaulted by a group of Chinese gangsters. Vastra stepped in and rescued her, with the rest being, as they say, history.

> [image]
> <sub>*"Why, only the other night I came across a young match girl being
> molested by a Chinese Gang. These Tongs are everywhere and forever
> dragging young girls off, presumably as part of a mating ritual. So, I
> stepped in and made short work of her assailants. The match girl had fainted clean
> away so I conveyed her back to my apartments."*</sub>

Comment: I find it rather amusing that Vastra, who grew up in a volcano, thinks that Jenny (a match girl) smells pleasant. presumably because she reeks of sulphur.